# MVC .Net Trigger Button Click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I do not even know how to explain this other than I want a predefined search button to trigger a click on page load.  This is an asp MVC application.

The search button is defined as:

```
<ID="SearchButton" runat="server" ImageCSS="button-search"Text="Resource:Search"  ClientClicked="Shr.panel.mylisting.search(); "/>
```

The code behind has an OnLoad that I was trying to use to trigger a click, but I have had no success.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  Page.AddJavaScriptReference("myscript.js");
  initiateJobSearch();
}
```

Finally you can see that the page references Js that return the results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is web forms, not MVC

Comment: What is `Shr.panel.mylisting.search();`? What is `initiateJobSearch`? Can't you just call `Shr.panel.mylisting.search()` on document.ready?

Comment: Thank you for the replies folks.  I added the following to the js to trigger the event.


//line added make sure the search is displayed on load
        setTimeout('Shr.panel.JobOpenings.search()', 100);]